# How can I make an css element hug another element below or above itself?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make multible CSS shapes hug each-other. Upon googling, the only advice I found was that I should be using inline-block. However, I can't seem to get it to work as I would like. While it allows shapes next to each other to hug, it doesn't seem to allow shapes to hug elements above and below them.

Example: If I am trying to make a dimond out of triangles:

```css
.r_tleft {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 0 25px 25px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #007bff transparent;
  display: inline-block;
}

.r_tright {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 25px 0 0 25px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #64C7CC;
  display: inline-block;
}

.r_bleft {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 25px 25px 0;
  border-color: transparent #64C7CC transparent transparent;
  display: inline-block;
}

.r_bright {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 25px 25px 0 0;
  border-color: #007bff transparent transparent transparent;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="r_tleft"></div>
<div class="r_tright"></div>
<div class="r_bleft"></div>
<div class="r_bright"></div>
```

Result looks something like this:

◢◣◥◤

If I was to add a break, like so...

```
<div class="r_tleft"></div><div class="r_tright"></div>
<br>
<div class="r_bleft"></div><div class="r_bright"></div>
```

```css
.r_tleft {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 0 25px 25px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #007bff transparent;
  display: inline-block;
}

.r_tright {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 25px 0 0 25px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #64C7CC;
  display: inline-block;
}

.r_bleft {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 25px 25px 0;
  border-color: transparent #64C7CC transparent transparent;
  display: inline-block;
}

.r_bright {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 25px 25px 0 0;
  border-color: #007bff transparent transparent transparent;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="r_tleft"></div>
<div class="r_tright"></div>
<br>
<div class="r_bleft"></div>
<div class="r_bright"></div>
```

This happens instead:

◢◣

◥◤

As implied, neither of theese have the desired result.

Comment: if inline-block is involved, then you may reset line-height and font-size to 0 to get rid of white space. negative margin could be used too at some points https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/KvYGRP

Comment: I'm must be out of touch, or this is an English idiom that I don't know, but what means "hug" in this context? Having the four shapes without any space between them? In that case, what do you want to get, the four shapes in a line forming a parallelogram like in the first example, or the four shapes in two lines in a diamond shape (or both)?

Comment: I wanted the four shapes to all be touching without any visible space between them -- so that together the would look like this: ◆

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost had it, but take into account that making elements `inline-block` makes them, well, inline, so line properties are applied to them. In your case you remove the vertical space adjusting the `line-height` on the *container* block:

```css
.r_tleft {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 0 25px 25px;
    border-color: transparent transparent #007bff transparent;
    display:inline-block;
}

.r_tright {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 25px 0 0 25px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #64C7CC;
    display:inline-block;
}

.r_bleft {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 25px 25px 0;
    border-color: transparent #64C7CC transparent transparent;
    display:inline-block;
}

.r_bright {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 25px 25px 0 0;
    border-color: #007bff transparent transparent transparent;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div style="line-height: 0px">
  <div class="r_tleft"></div><div class="r_tright"></div>
  <br>
  <div class="r_bleft"></div><div class="r_bright"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap each of your items in divs you will get the desired effect. Then you can use css on the wrapper div to get them as closes as you want.

```css
.r_tleft {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 0 25px 25px;
    border-color: transparent transparent #007bff transparent;
    display:inline-block;
}

.r_tright {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 25px 0 0 25px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #64C7CC;
    display:inline-block;
}

.r_bleft {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 25px 25px 0;
    border-color: transparent #64C7CC transparent transparent;
    display:inline-block;
}

.r_bright {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 25px 25px 0 0;
    border-color: #007bff transparent transparent transparent;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
 <div><div class="r_tleft"></div><div class="r_tright"></div></div>
    <div><div class="r_bleft"></div><div class="r_bright"></div></div>
```

Comment: Sorry pressed submit before I was done :P Here is the edited version.